# Can I Program a Website with Ruby on Rails and NOT have Speghetti Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have abandoned php because it was a nightmare to maintain. I then reprogrammed the whole site in asp.net C# Which is so much better. The maintenance is a breeze. I have lately been hearing alot of good stories about RoR but I don't want to develop software in this language if it is like PHP speghetti code. So, can I make web applications with RoR and not have to mess around with html mixed with code?

Comment: it is possible to write non-spaghetti code PHP

Comment: The question is pretty loaded. Writing non-spaghetti code is a function of pattern as much as it is of language. A solid MVC framework can do wonders for PHP. I'd still vote for a better language though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, quite easily. Rails *very* strongly encourages a model-view-controller structure for your application. It's possible to put business code into your views, but it's pretty unnatural. Try working through one of the tutorials on the Rails site. They only take maybe 15 minutes and will give you a good idea of how things are structured in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

The whole MVC architecture is really aimed at more precise, segmented code, so following in line with the MVC model keeps the code clean by design!!